# Regex compatibility across multiple shells

Tags: regex, bash, shell, format, dash-shell

I'm checking correct date format in my bash script with following code:

```
if [[ $variable == [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9] ]]
```

The format should be: YYYY-MM-DD

This works well in bash, however I have problems when trying to run it in dash or sh. Could you help me rewriting this so it's compatible with dash and sh? Or alternatively find a different solution that can be used on all shells?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`case` should work in dash, too:

```
case 0015-18-32 in 
    [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9] ) echo yes ;;
esac
```